# How to add column value in SQL Server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I created a table called `Dummy` with 4 columns: `Date, Year, Student_Names, Subject`.

After a few days I need to add one more column name called `Marks`.

I know how to add column `Marks` by using the SQL query, I am using the query below:

```
Alter Table Dummy 
add Mark varchar(30)
```

After I add the column, all values are NULL, I need some value in the place of NULL.

How do I add those values? Values are mentioned in an Excel file.

Comment: You can update the previous rows having NULL values.

Comment: It sounds as if you're planning to store **multiple values** into your columns like `Student_Names` and `Marks` - this is a **horribly bad** idea - you should never do this. It violates even the **first normal form** of database design - one cell (row/column) contains exactly one value (or nothing) - but **not** multiple values - that's one of the core principles of basic database design.

Comment: I agree with techdo: add a column that allows NULL, update the values as appropriate, and then remove NULL'ability unless required .. you'll have to find out how to load the data from Excel, which is a *different* question.

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
Alter Table Dummy ADD Mark varchar(30) DEFAULT ''
```

or

```
UPDATE Dummy
SET [MArk] = 'new value'
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is `update Dummy set Marks = 10 where Student_Names = name you want to add marks to`

like this you can add marks to all the students

good luck

Comment: I have N number of student have can I apply where condition each student ? there is any other way to add this marks ?

Answer (score 1):

You can update NULL values:

```
UPDATE Dummy
  SET Mark = "none"
WHERE Mark is NULL
```

Will set all the marks to "none".

Also, when adding the column, you can specify a default value:

```
ADD Mark varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none'
```

Comment: See the new edit.  I thought mark was an int for some silly reason.

Comment: What are the "different values"?

Comment: Values : 42,45,,26,87,96,48,65,24,6,45,57,59,245,356,24, etc

Comment: Like the other responsers, I misread your question.  The easiest way is to use SQL Server Management Studio to import an excel file.  Here's the step by step instructions: http://www.66pacific.com/sql_server_import_from_excel.aspx

Comment: Also, I suggest changing the `Mark` datatype to an `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

To update values present in Excel sheet you need to write Query in Excel file(using CONCATENATE function) and run it on the table.